# Browser auth popup not showing up in case of ajax cors with basic authentication request

Tags: ajax, cors, basic-authentication

From a web page of domain A, I am firing up an ajax request to domain B in order to get JSON for which basic auth is configured on domain B. I have access to the code on both the domains.
 
I configured the all the required CORS header on domain B (Even made Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value specific and not "*", after reading some stackoverflow) 
What I am expecting is browser basic auth pop up, But POST request just fails with 401.
I can see that server has responded with expected response header for PRE-FLIGHT OPTION request, below the request & response headers of the OPTION & actual POST method call that happens

```
***OPTION REQUEST***
Host: DOMAIN_B:8085
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
Referer: http://DOMAIN_A:2280/app/
Origin: http://DOMAIN_A:2280
Connection: keep-alive
```

```
***OPTION RESPONSE***
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://DOMAIN_A:2280
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1
Allow: GET,POST
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 12:48:48 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

```
*** ACTUAL POST REQUEST***
Host: DOMAIN_B:8085
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://DOMAIN_A:2280/app/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 105
Origin: http://DOMAIN_A:2280
Connection: keep-alive
```

```
*** ACTUAL POST REQUEST***
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://DOMAIN_A:2280
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=artist
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 12:48:48 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

So its expected that browser looking at the response of the POST call(401 HTTP code & WWW-Authenticate header) should get prompted to show the native authentication pop up, But it's not doing so. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Showing custom form to capture the credential and passing them in `"Authorization"` header using `btoa` function is not an option
Appreciate any help, I am ripping my hair apart here!!!

Answer (score 1):

use [basic-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth) npm plugin

```
const auth = require('basic-auth');
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  var user = auth(request);
  console.log("user => ",user);
  if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
    response.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"');
    return response.status(401).send();
  }
  return next();
});
```

Comment: For API call basic auth works, if we pass the authorization header. But my problem is browser not showing the basic auth pop up.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it. I hope it will work for both (API and WEB)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, so there are couple of things that needs to be accounted for if you want to do CORS/authenticated request
1) CORS Server needs to allow the origin specifically and not just doing via "*"(by setting the appropriate header in the preflight OPTIONS request)
2) authorization header needs to  be in list of allowed header
3) AJAX request has to be fired with xhr.withCredentials = true.
My problem was I was using ExtJS for firing up the AJAX and setting withCredential flag to true in ExtJs ajax object doesn't turn the XHR.withCredentials to true, It seems to be bug